# Assigning MIN(value) based on/grouped by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using Microsoft SQL (SSMS):

| UPC | Item | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0 |
| 2 | b | 23 |
| 3 | c | 33 |
| 4 | a | 0 |

I'm trying to write a query where if [Department] = 0, assign [UPC] as 'Department'

In this example, **[Item]=a** will have two [UPC] values with different [Department] values.
I'm trying to assign min([UPC] based on [Item] so I can see the following output:

| UPC | Item | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 4 | a | 1 |

This is what I have so far and I know this is wrong. Can anyone help me out with this query?
Thank you!

```
SELECT h.[UPC], h.[Item]
    CASE WHEN h.[Department] = 0 THEN
    CASE WHEN count(h.[UPC]) = 1 THEN h.[UPC]
        ELSE f.[Min_UPC] END
    ELSE h.[Department] END AS 'Department' 
FROM [table]h
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT [Item], MIN([UPC]) AS 'Min_UPC' FROM [table]
    GROUP BY [Item])f on h.[Item] = f.[Item]
GROUP BY h.[UPC], h.[Item], f.[Min_UPC], h.[Department]
```

Comment: So you need to min UPC by item? I also don't get the "if [Department] = 0, assign [UPC] as 'Department'" statement as this is not what shows in the sample resultset where `Department` is `1` for both rather than `1` & `4`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. The second table is what I'm hoping to achieve and yes MIN UPC by item. So in the first table, since Department is 0 for Item A, I want to assign 1 as Department for both rows. Does this make sense?

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use single quotes for identifiers such as column aliases. Yes, sadly SQL Server accepts that, but in SQL single quotes are usually for string (or date...) literals. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future SQL Server versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an error. Use square brackets for identifiers that have special characters in them or are case sensitive or preferably don't use special characters and case sensitive identifiers at all. Identifiers don't need to be "pretty", "pretty" headers and such are a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: That's a great tip, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the windowed version of `min()` to get the minimum `upc` for each item and assign it when `department` equals `0` using a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT upc,
       item,
       CASE
         WHEN department = 0 THEN
           min(upc) OVER (PARTITION BY item)
         ELSE
           department
       END AS department
       FROM elbat;
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @pepsidecay Be sure to ACCEPT the answer.   It is an easy way to show your appreciation for the contributor's time and talent.  It also serves as an indicator that the issue has been resolved.